# Understanding the types of discontinuities admitted into limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, fake-proofs

Let $f: A \subseteq \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous on $A$.  Let $g(a) = \lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ be defined on all $A$.  Is $g$ necessarily continuous?

I am confused about the answer, since I have what seem to be valid arguments in both ways:

**A limit can have discontinuities.** Every derivative is a limit of a continuous function, yet derivatives can have discontinuities, the classic example being the derivative of $0 \mapsto 0, x \mapsto x^2 \sin  1/x$.

**A limit must be continuous**.  Since $f$ is continuous on $A$, $f$ is equal to its limit on $A$.  Thus, $g$, which is the limit of $f$, equals $f$, and since $f$ is continuous, $g$ is continuous as well.

This argument seems to be valid *provided* that $a \in A$.  However, for $a \notin A$, this argument is not applicable.  This would suggest: $g$ may have points of discontinuity, but they must be on the boundary of $A$, because they are limit points of $A$ but not elements of $A$.  But the example above has discontinuities in the middle of its domain.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your second argument is essentially correct, provided that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists at each $a$ (which is given). In your first argument, what do you mean by "every derivative is a limit of a continuous function"? Can you turn your idea into an actual counterexample?

Comment: @Karl I tried to turn my idea into a counterexample but was not able to.  Can you get me started? By "every derivative is a limit of a continuous function", I mean $g(a) = f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} h(x)$ for some $h$ (namely $\frac {f(a) - f(x)}{a - x}$), and $h$ must be continuous for $f'$ to be defined.

Comment: I see - the problem with that is you have a different function $h_a(x)$ for each $a$ (with the additional problem that $h_a$ is undefined at $a$), so you aren't going to obtain a function that is both a derivative and a limit in the required sense. Your second argument (that $g=f$) is correct.

Comment: @Karl I understand the two issues you raise: that $h_a$ is different than $h_{a+\varepsilon}$ and that $h_a$ is undefined at $a$, but nonetheless am still confused: it's not clear to me how these differences suffice to allow $g$ to vary discontinuously at points near $a$.

Comment: There is a result which says: if $I$ is a non-empty interval and $f:I\to\mathbb{R} $ is such that $g(a) =\lim_{x\to a} f(x) $ exists for all $a\in I$ then $g$ is continuous on $I$ irrespective of the continuity of $f$. Your second example is a much simpler case of this theorem.

Comment: And for the first example a derivative is not the limit of a continuous function. Rather derivative is defined using a limit of an expression related to the function and continuity of derivative is not related to the continuity of function.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can you expand on this distinction? I see how "technically" the difference is there, in that a derivative at $a$ incorporates $a$ into the function.  But, despite my efforts, I haven't been able to work this our clearly, which is why I came to math.SE.

Comment: @SRobertJames it's unclear what you're trying to do or what you're still confused about. Do you agree that your derivative construction doesn't work?

Comment: When you write "a limit can have discontinuities" or "a limit must be continuous" you need to pay attention to what you're taking the limit with respect to, and what you're measuring continuity with respect to. After all, *every* number is the limit of *something*, and so *any* function can be expressed as a limit at each point. The fact that a derivative (which happens to be defined using a limit expression) can be discontinuous does not imply that the limit of a *fixed* continuous function, *viewed as a function of the limit location*, can be discontinuous.